# React button background change on toggle giving error (Using React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change/toggle background of a button using inline-styling in React but getting error (in functional component).

**Snippet:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Home2 = () => {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  btnClick = () => {
    setStatus(!status);
  }

  return (
    <div><button onClick={btnClick} style={{background: status? 'orange': 'pink'}}>click 2</button></div>
  )

}

export default Home2;
```

**Error:**

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: You forgot to declare `btnClick`. Use `const btnClick = () => {`.

Comment: you are missing the variable keyword (const/let)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define your btnClick with const.

```
const btnClick = () => {
    setStatus(!status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change a bit your code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

  const Home2 = () => {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  const btnClick = () => {
    setStatus(!status);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={btnClick}
        style={{background: status? 'orange': 'pink'}}
      >
         click 2
      </button>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Home2;
```

You missed `const` in the function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot const:

```js
const Home2 = () => {

  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(false);

  const btnClick = () => {//you forgot const here
    setStatus(status=>!status);//just to be save, use a callback
  }

  return (
    <div><button onClick={btnClick} style={{background: status? 'orange': 'pink'}}>click 2</button></div>
  )

}


ReactDOM.render(<Home2 />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly define the callback function. In classes, we reference callbacks with `this`. In hooks, `this` is omitted (luckily) so you have to define a function explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not defined the `btnClick` function. The way it is declared is incorrect. Below should work.

```
const Home2 = () => {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  const btnClick = () => {
    setStatus(!status);
  }

  return (
    <div><button onClick={btnClick} style={{background: status? 'orange': 'pink'}}>click 2</button></div>
  )

}

export default Home2;
```

The way you have declared `btnClick` is a syntax we follow in `class` based components. In functional component, you need `let` or `const` to declare variables/functions.